# Move Pointers backward in assembly language

Tags: assembly

I am trying to move file pointers backward relative to the end of the file.This is waht I am doing-

```
.model tiny
.386
.data
fil1    db      'testing.txt',0
dat1    db      100 dup('$')
dat2    db      100 dup('$')
.code
.startup
        mov     al,02h
        lea     dx,fil1
        mov     ah,3dh
        int     21h



        mov     bx,ax
        mov     al,2    
        mov     cx,0
        mov     dx,-3
        mov     ah,42h
        int     21h



        lea     dx,dat1
        mov     cx,2
        mov     ah,3fh
        int     21h


        lea     dx,dat1
        mov     ah,09h
        int     21h



        mov     ah,3eh
        int     21h
.exit
end
```

But this is not displaying anything on the console.I dont know where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The description of `INT 21H / AH=42H` says:

> `CX:DX` = (signed) offset from origin of new file position

By setting `cx = 0` you're specifying the positive offset 0x0000FFFD (65533) rather than the negative offset -3 (0xFFFFFFFD). You should set `cx = 0xFFFF` instead (which can also be expressed as `cx = -1`).